# How to Convert WAV file int MP3 file in C# NETCF(windows mobile)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, mp3, wav

How to Convert WAV file int MP3 file in C# NETCF(windows mobile)????
Maybe somebody know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is direct conversion within the .net compactframework, however the followign library does provide the functionality 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Aumplib.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As it was stated before, this is not possible with .netcf alone. However I have used this project http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MP3Compressor.aspx myself in Windows Mobile with some minor modifications and it worked fine.